# Unable to bulk create document using nest and elasticsearch Error reading string. "Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'items[0].create.error'"

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to bulk create document which already exists in ElasticSearch.

```
descriptor.Create<D>(op => op.Document((D)baseNotice));

    _elasticClient.Bulk(descriptor);
```

I have got serializer exception there

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Elasticsearch.Net.dll

Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'items[0].create.error', line 1, position 123.
```

The index method works but I need to use create operation

```
descriptor.Index<D>(op => op.Document((D)baseNotice));
```

Comment: Maybe problem is that I use ElasticSearch 2.1 version and NEST 1.7.1 which is not compatible regarding to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix ...

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch and what version of NEST are you using?

Comment: I've had written it: ElasticSearch 2.1 version and NEST 1.7.1 probably something has changed in bulk response schema and is not correctly serialized to response object model using Newtonsoft serializer...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can go through your list of bulk and remove the ones that already exist and then call create. 
You can use a multiGet for checking existence of docs you are going to create.

Comment: No, it is not possibile I would like to use create operation from NEST library but there is problem in deserialisation elasticsearch response.